# problem with autocomplete search with linq and datagrid

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, search

I would like to do a search which populates the result to a Gridview with LINQ.

This is the code before I used  Linq which works fine:

```
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("Name like  '" + txtSearch.Text + "%'"))
        {
            dtable.ImportRow(dr);
        }
```

In my linq code, I used `bsUser` as the BindingSource.

```
 private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string input = txtSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower();
        if (input.Length <= 0) return;

        IList<User> u = (bsUser.Filter? select?
                        .Where(x => (x.Name.ToLower().StartsWith(input) 
                        && (x.RoleId == (int)cbRole.SelectedValue))).ToList());

        bsUser.DataSource = u;            

    }
```

The problem I have is, if the `u` returns 0 rows, then my Gridview which bound to the `bsUser` will no longer have data. `datasource.count() = 0`

Could someone give me a workaround or advice on how I could tackle this?

Comment: Please confirm? You don't want the Grid to update when the search query returns NO results?

Comment: i want the grid to show empty if the query returns NO result.

Answer (score 0):

hi i think i have done that by using this way. Looks good though..

```
  private void txtSearch_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = txtSearch.Text.Trim().ToLower();
        if (input.Length > 0)
            bsUser.Filter = "Name like '" + input + "%' AND RoleId = '" + (int)cbRoleSearch.SelectedValue + "'";
        else
            FilterCBRoleSearch(Convert.ToInt16(cbRoleSearch.SelectedValue));
    }
```

Comment: ok, weird.. i can only do the bindingSource Filter if it is bounded with datatable. It cant filter if i bind it with tolist(). I am ok it bind with datatable, but i have hard time getting the databoundItem on MouseUp event() when i click on the gridview row. '    tutor = (User)gvTutor.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;' This line failed if my gridview is bounded with datatable. the dataBoundItem works well in Tolist()